# Electron remote is always undefined

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using `Electron 10` and `Node v12.6.3`.

I try to open a FileDialog **from the renderer process**. This is not the first question on SO regarding this problem, but I can't find any solution that works for me. `nodeIntegrations` is enabled

```js
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      webSecurity: false,
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      allowRunningInsecureContent: (serve) ? true : false,
    },
```

I tried the following:

```
1) import * as electron from "electron";
2) import { remote } from "electron";
3) var remote = require("electron").remote;
...
```

Also executing `require("electron").remote` within a function return `undefined`. What could I miss here?

In any instance `remote` seems to be undefined. Can anyone help me? I am lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [#21408](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21408)

> In Electron 10.x, set the default value of enableRemoteModule to false. Apps that use remote will need to update to explicitly set enableRemoteModule to true.